# Pick and crop image not working choosing google photos

Tags: android, xml

I pick a image google photos only return can't find item.

This is the code to create intent for selecting photo:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY);
```

Following my `activityresult` code:

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case REQUEST_CODE_FROM_GALLERY:
                        Utils.toast_center(Main_Theme.this,""+data.getData());
                        try {
                            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                            File mydir = new File(root + "/Image");
                            mydir.mkdirs();
                            String fname = "user_image.jpg";
                            final File file = new File(mydir, fname);
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                            intent1.setType("image/*");
                            intent1.setData(data.getData()); // Uri to the image you want to crop
                            intent1.putExtra("scale", true);
                            intent1.putExtra("circleCrop", new String(""));
                            intent1.putExtra("return-data", false);
                            intent1.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                            startActivityForResult(intent1, 03);
                        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                            Utils.toast_center(Main_Theme.this,"Something Went Error. Try Again");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 03:

                        File filee = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "//Image/user_image.jpg");

                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filee.getPath());
                        iconn.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        settheame();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the precise error? What says the logcat?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 0):

When you select google photo image then URI start likes `"content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/"` and it's not from the local device.

Local uri like `content://media/external/images/media/49518`

So you need to first check the URI and based on that you need to get image from server or local image.

You can use DocumentsProvider API.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException 
{
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
             getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return image;
}
```